# Image coloring in django

Tags: django, image-processing

I am currently writing a two player game with django, and would like the user to be able to choose their color (while not necessary, it adds a nice touch). I'm not sure how to do the image processing, though.

One approach would be to restrict the user to a set of ~8-10 colors, then manually generate all of the images, but that just seems really tedious, restrictive, and difficult to maintain. I would prefer something more automated/extensible. Is there any good way of doing this? I have not created the base artwork yet, so I don't care what the original image format is.

Comment: To get better answers, you might want to add an example of the "colorize" effect you're seeking. Potentially useful: ["Python: Colorize image while preserving transparency with PIL"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251896/python-colorize-image-while-preserving-transparency-with-pil).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what pricisely it is that I want, since I've never done image-processing before. The link you posted is definitely a good start. The suggestions provided on that page would work. It would be nice to do it in such a way that doesn't restrict the available colors. All the suggestions provided on that page convert to grayscale first. I also know that I can't have everything, so this may not be possible. I'm sorry for my lack of clarity.